# Save output of generic listview into html-file

Tags: django, django-views

Using django I get the correct output displayed in the browser when direct it to right URL after login and add the needed query string (GET) parameters.
Now I would like - from a different view - to get the aforementioned output and save it directly into a (server side) (html) file.

Do I need to construct an `HttpRequest` object? What settings are required there? How to I get the content out of the `HttpResponse`?
Or is there a simpler solution?

Comment: What have you done ? And what is the result did you expect ?

Comment: I did not get anything there yet.  I started building HttpRequest, instatiantiate the view class. Then I ran into problems with user object.

Comment: I found a solution by calling `render_to_string` and fiddling an "ok" request object to add an objects_list .... and so on ...